# How to send an image using udpsink or tcpsink in gstreamer over the same network

Tags: tcp, udp, gstreamer

I have an image file image.jpg and I want to send this image file from my Raspberry Pi to my PC (Windows) over the same network through Gstreamer using udpsink or tcpsink. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you try to simply gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location = file_name.img  ! udpsink host=192.1XX.XX.XX port=9001 ? and on the other end do a udpsrc and write to drive using filesink.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port = 9001 ! filesink location="C:\Desktop\image.jpg"

will this work for the receiver?

Comment: yes It should, try it. You can always pipe it to fakesink to see if the bytes are coming through instead of the filesink.

Comment: So I am using the following on the sender, 

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc -v filesrc location=/home/pi/image0.jpg ! udpsink host=192.xxx.xxx.xxx port=6000

and the follwoing on the receiver,

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6000 ! filesink location="C:\Users\Desktop\image0.jpg"

The sender pipeline executes but the reciever pipeline wont end, any idea? forgive me if I a asking stupid questions I am new to Gstreamer

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc -v filesrc location=/home/pi/image0.jpg ! udpsink host=192.xxx.xxx.xxx port=6000 sync = false and receiver  gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6000 ! filesink location="C:\Users\Desktop\image0.jpg" - what do you mean doesn't end? Has the image been transfered whats the size of C:\users\bla.img.jpg?

Comment: The sender rsults in,
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.003727228
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
 
whereas receiver is stuck at,

Setting pipeline to PLAYING...

Comment: start the receiver first, then the transmit.

Comment: I am staring the receiver first

Comment: I am using the PC as a user and not as an administrator, could that be a problem?

Comment: Maybe try saving it to a different location

Comment: i am using linux and give the send and recv commands in two separate bash terminals, the send `gst-launch-1.0 -vvv filesrc location=h264.raw ! udpsink port=9002`
command always terminates immediately after issuing the command, and recv command `gst-launch-1.0  udpsrc port=9002 ! filesink location=/tmp/rrr` always gets stuck. exactly the same results as @FarzanZaheer mentioned.

Comment: sorry past 5 mins restriction, have to use another "comment" to finish my question.   is it true the sender always has to start after the receiver for udpsink?  if so, does this mean that udpsink is never can be a "server", blocked and wait for connection?  and any sink can play as server?